# SQL ORDER BY not working with varchar date

Tags: sql

I have a query which is not ordering as i spect, also I think is a very simple order by but somehow is not working.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT 
    'May 19 2020  9:07AM' AS D
UNION
SELECT
    'May 19 2020  9:04PM'
) AS A
ORDER BY A.D DESC
```

The spected behavior is that 'May 19 2020  9:04PM' should be in the first row, as this is oldest.

Comment: which SQL engine are you using?

Comment: Why are you using a `DESC` sort if you want the oldest first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert it to `date()` in order by. Here is the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2cBx8K1hb57AEwGPrQMmo6/1).

This solution should work in SQL Server, PostgreSQL and SQL Lite

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT 
    'May 19 2020  9:07AM' AS D
UNION
SELECT
    'May 19 2020  9:04PM'
) AS A
ORDER BY date(D) DESC
```

Output:

```
| d                   |
| ------------------- |
| May 19 2020  9:04PM |
| May 19 2020  9:07AM |
```

If you are using MySQL then `unix_timestamp(d) desc` should do the trick.

Comment: I'm using SQL Server but the point you show is the same, the only difference is that I did a CAST(D DATE). Thanks so much